# Latex Error: File `readarray.sty` not found

Tags: verbatim

all, I tried to use `\usepackage{verbatimbox,xcolor}`, and when I tried to `TeXify` my `tex` file, an error message popped up (after install `verbatimbox`):

```
! Latex Error: File `readarray.sty` not found.
```

How to fix this error?

I am using `MiKTeX2.9` with `WinEdt7.1` on `Win7 X64`.

[EDIT1] I have installed both `verbatimbox`(`WinEdt` promoted) and `xcolor`(using `MiKTeX Package Manager`) packages, but the error persists.

[EDIT2] The problem has been resolved using the method suggested by `Segletes`. `Refresh FNDB` in `MiKTex Maintenance` ->`Settings`.

cheers

Comment: By installing it. Ask MikTeX to install it. In most cases MikTeX will automatically come and ask the users if it should install a missing package. But some editors does not allow this popup message.

Comment: @daleif `WinEdt` did let me install any missing package. The error message just popped up after the installation.

Comment: Just for the fun of it, what happens if you compile without the editor, jsut to rule it out, i.e. from a dos prompt.

Comment: @daleif I am wondering how to do that? Compiling without using `WinEdt`? Command lines? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The package is available at http://ctan.org/pkg/readarray.  By downloading and placing the .sty file in your working directory, you should have access to it.  In the long run, you should place it in the local texmf directory for your installation.  On my system, for MikTeX 2.9, that is `C:\Users\steven.segletes\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex` though obviously your user name will be different.

Comment: @daiyue Have you tried installing `readarray` with MikTeX' Package Manager?

Comment: the package is available through the standard miktex package manager ... unless (a) your miktex is _sooo_ old it doesn't work with the current repositories (needs to be three years old, i think), or (b) you don't have a network connection to do the download.

Comment: It is already stated that the OP is using MikTeX 2.9, so the mirrors should hold it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I downloaded `readarray` package, unzip it and put it in both `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\readarray` and `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\readarray`, but when I `TeXify` `tex` file, it still game me the same error message

Comment: If I entered the path name containing `readarray.sty`, `TeXify` threw me `! Undefined control sequence.` error.

Comment: If you place the sty file in the working directory (i.e., the same directory as your `.tex` file), all should be OK.  If you place it in a directory called `readarray` below the directory mentioned in my former comment, you need to update your filename database (FNDB) using the MikTeX maintenance manager or, if you work from a Windows command prompt, `texhash` will accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the OP's request, I am turning my comments into an answer.  When one's LaTeX installation can't locate a package, your only option is to install it yourself.  First you have to locate the missing package.  A good place to start is the repository at `ctan.org`.  In this case, the `readarray` package that I wrote is stored there in http://ctan.org/pkg/readarray .  Failing that, there is always a google search to try to locate an obscure package (disclaimer: be careful what you download from unknown sites).

Some packages are easier to install than others.  In the simplest cases (for which `readarray` qualifies), there is a `.sty` file that is directly downloadable.  For more complicated installations, the package should hopefully provide installation instructions.

LaTeX is set up so that if you place the needed `.sty` file in your working directory, it will be located and used.  This can get you over the hump in the short term, but ideally, you would like to place the file in the "proper" place.  There are typically (at least) two directory trees in a LaTeX installation, the tree where the system's installation  resides.  On a MikTeX installation, for example, that would be `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9`.

You don't want to mess with that directory tree manually, unless you know what you are doing,  What you want to find is the "local" LaTeX installation directory tree, historically referred to as the `localtexmf` (on Unix systems).  In the default MikTeX installation, each user gets his own local installation directory, and so it has a name (in my case) of `C:\Users\steven.segletes\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9`.  Obviously, the directory name should reflect the name of user in question.  MikTeX also permits, through the "Roots" tab of its `Settings` program, to add your own local installation directory (I also have one called `C:\localtexmf`).

The structure of the directory tree in this local directory (regardless of it pathname) has some standard locations to put things.

`\tex\latex` - directories where `.sty` files can be placed

`\source\latex` - directories where source code goes (I use it for `.dtx`, `.ins`, and other such files)

`\doc\latex` - PDF package documentation, and the `.tex` files for producing the documentation

`\bibtex\bst` - BibTeX styles

`\bibtex\bib` -  standard bibfile data

There are many others, but these are the main ones I use.  So, in my case, I would want to move the readarray style file to

`C:\Users\steven.segletes\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\readarray\readarray.sty`

or (since I created a secondary local LaTeX directory)

`C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\readarray\readarray.sty`

as its proper repository location (I even keep a shortcut to `C:\Users\steven.segletes\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex` on my desktop to quickly access these directories).  You can similarly move documentation, etc., as described above.

The only thing left (**and it is essential**) is to let MikTeX know that you have placed the file in this location.  From a Windows command prompt (program `cmd`) you need to run

`C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texhash`

Alternately, from the MikTeX settings program, you need to click on the "Refresh FNDB" button, which updates the filename database.

Your installation of `readarray.sty` should now be ready to use.